# How do I stop my browsers creating a new tab for every new domain?

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, web-browsing

I have a MacBook and have tried browsing with both the Safari 7 and the Chrome browsers, but every time I go from one domain to another, it automatically creates a new tab. So if I click a link that goes from Yahoo to, say, the IMDB, it will create a new tab for the IMDB site.

This is really annoying because the back button will only navigate me back to the beginning of the history for that domain.

On my PC, no new tabs are created unless I specifically create them.

Is there any way I can prevent this behaviour?

Comment: This isn't standard behaviour. Do you have any browser plugins installed?

Comment: Definitely not standard behaviour. If it happens with both Safari and Chrome, and you have no knowledge of installing specific extensions for that purpose - I would guess that you have been infected with malware or similar. Some free programs bundle browser extensions with their installers that are not always obvious to spot. They can wreck havoc with standard browsing features in order to for example direct traffic to a specific search engine or ad network. You might want to check the extensions/add-ons list for Safari/Chrome to ensure that you haven't got anything installed there.